# Most efficient way to return Eigen::VectorXi with more than 2^31-1 elements to R

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppeigen

I have a vector `x` of type `Eigen::VectorXi` with more than 2^31-1 entries, which I would like to return to R. I can do that by copying `x` entry-wisely to a new vector of type `Rcpp::IntegerVector`, but that seems to be quite slow.

I am wondering:

1. whether there is a more efficient workaround;
2. why in the following reproducible example `Rcpp::wrap(x)` doesn't work.

test.cpp

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP foo(const R_xlen_t size) {
  Eigen::VectorXi x(size);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    x(i) = 1;
  }
  return Rcpp::wrap(x);
}
    
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector fooSlow(const R_xlen_t size) {
  Eigen::VectorXi x(size);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    x(i) = 1;
  }
  Rcpp::IntegerVector y(size);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    y(i) = x(i);
  }   
  return y;
}
```

test.R

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("./test.cpp")
a <- foo(2^(31)) # Error in foo(2^(31)) : negative length vectors are not allowed
a <- fooSlow(2^(31)) # runs fine but it's slow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rcpp::wrap` is dispatching to a method for Eigen matrices and vectors implemented in `RcppEigen`. That method doesn't appear to support [long vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Long-vectors), currently. (**Edit:** It now *does*; see below.)

The error about negative length is thrown by `allocVector3` [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/cf48dffbb8d85eec13a24b4b9e94fb526f23dd9e/src/main/memory.c#L2688). It arises when `allocVector3` is called with a negative value for its argument `length`. My *guess* is that `Rcpp::wrap` tries to represent `2^31` as an `int`, resulting in integer overflow. Maybe this happens [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/106c26b46e43a0852f210c25dd78ffa3885ad83e/inst/include/RcppEigenWrap.h#L89)?

In any case, you seem to have stumbled on a bug, so you might consider sharing your example with the `RcppEigen` maintainers on [GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/issues). (**Edit:** Never mind - I've just submitted a [patch](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/pull/105).) (**Edit:** Patched now, if you'd like to build `RcppEigen` from sources [commit [5fd125e](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/tree/5fd125ea911c24615ce610b41688cf1d0420280c) or later] in order to update your `Rcpp::wrap`.)

Attempting to answer your first question, I compared your two approaches with my own based on [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy). The `std::memcpy` approach supports long vectors and is only slightly slower than `Rcpp::wrap`.

#### The `std::memcpy` approach

The C arrays beneath `Eigen::VectorXi x` and `Rcpp::IntegerVector y` have the same type (`int`) and length (`n`), so they contain the same number of bytes. You can use `std::memcpy` to copy that number of bytes from one's memory address to other's without a `for` loop. The hard part is knowing how to obtain the addresses. `Eigen::VectorXi` has a member function `data` that returns the address of the underlying `int` array. R objects of integer type use `INTEGER` from the R API, which does the same thing.

#### Tests

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector f_for(const R_xlen_t n) {
  Eigen::VectorXi x(n);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x(i) = i % 10;
  }
  Rcpp::IntegerVector y(n);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    y(i) = x(i);
  }
  return y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector f_wrap(const R_xlen_t n) {
  Eigen::VectorXi x(n);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x(i) = i % 10;
  }
  return Rcpp::wrap(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector f_memcpy(const R_xlen_t n) {
  Eigen::VectorXi x(n);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x(i) = i % 10;
  }
  Rcpp::IntegerVector y(n);
  memcpy(INTEGER(y), x.data(), n * sizeof(int));
  return y;
}
')
```

```r
n <- 100L
x <- rep_len(0:9, n)
identical(f_for(n),    x) # TRUE
identical(f_wrap(n),   x) # TRUE
identical(f_memcpy(n), x) # TRUE
```

```r
b <- function(n) microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f_for(n), f_wrap(n), f_memcpy(n), setup = gc(FALSE))

b(2^10)
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr   min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
##     f_for(n) 6.806 8.5280 15.09497 10.332 11.8900 461.496   100
##    f_wrap(n) 4.469 6.2115 12.60750  8.569  9.7170 435.420   100
##  f_memcpy(n) 4.633 7.0520 13.64193  9.061  9.6965 465.924   100

b(2^20)
## Unit: microseconds
##         expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
##     f_for(n) 3094.106 3118.2960 3160.2501 3132.4205 3171.329 3515.996   100
##    f_wrap(n)  864.690  890.0485  912.7006  905.4440  929.593  988.797   100
##  f_memcpy(n)  940.048  971.6590 1001.9805  987.3825 1009.195 1428.235   100

b(2^30)
## Unit: seconds
##         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##     f_for(n) 3.527164 3.554672 3.575698 3.573021 3.593006 3.693711   100
##    f_wrap(n) 1.119750 1.133130 1.143425 1.139702 1.149030 1.203602   100
##  f_memcpy(n) 1.304877 1.330994 1.343253 1.339099 1.354286 1.422912   100
```

Comment: `Rcpp` itself switches to using `R_xlen_t` a while back via several PRs; it is entirely possibly that `RcppEigen` has not kept up.  Careful contributions to extend its `Rcpp::wrap()` would certainly be welcomed.  Otherwise your approach here is sounds:  create the object R understands (here: `Rcpp::IntegerVector`) and fill its payload.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I've just created a [PR](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/pull/105). The changes are very minor. `f_wrap(2^31)` now works, at least. I trust you'll let me know if I've not been "careful" enough.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Now merged, with one minor editing patch in your branch. Hope that's ok.  Also added a ChangeLog entry.